# Is there a terminal based visualizer for linux that plays background music from default audio source?

Tags: terminal, audio

I was wondering whether there are any terminal based visualizers that work with the default background audio input in linux or unix?

For example, in order to use CLI visualizer, the MPD daemon needs to be running and the an audio file played in ncmpcpp player needs to be played in order for the visualizer to work (assuming that the config file has been set up properly).

Is there a terminal based visualizer that will work with just the default audio output. For example, can I play a youtube video in a browser and have the terminal based visualizer work?

Thank you in advance for any help or comments.

Comment: what do you mean by `visualizer`?

Comment: I mean a graphic visualizer for audio like the CLI visualizer

Comment: something like this? ... https://github.com/GallaFrancesco/mvc

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like [cava](https://github.com/karlstav/cava)

From the README.md :

> C.A.V.A.
> Console-based Audio Visualizer for ALSA
>
> also supports audio input from Pulseaudio, fifo (mpd), sndio, squeezelite and portaudio.